ag-grid - Date picker in the header filter is not closing on selection
I am using ag-grid in our React application application. I am using the date field and agDateColumnFilter for one of the columns. When I open the filter from the header and select a date, it does not close on selection. I have to manually click outside to close it.
Versions:
"react": "^18.2.0",
"ag-grid-community": "^31.0.1",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^31.0.1",
"ag-grid-react": "^31.0.1",

ColDef:
{
    headerName: "Last Updated On",
    field: "last_updated",
    sortable: true,
    type: "leftAligned",
    filter: "agDateColumnFilter",
    valueGetter: (params: any) => {
        return formatDate(params.data.last_updated);
    },
    filterParams: {
        comparator: dateComparator,
        minValidYear: 1900,
        maxValidYear: 3000,
    },
},

Grid:
<AgGridReact
    columnDefs={coldefs}
    rowData={data}
    pagination={false}
    defaultColDef={{
        wrapText: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        resizable: false,
        menuTabs: ["filterMenuTab", "columnsMenuTab"],
    }}
/>

Output (I have selected the date. It is not closing):

Could you please look into it and let me know if I am making any mistakes?
Thank you in advance.
